# Json message is converting when I apply jsonConverter at the sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have message in kafka as Json like
`{"name":"abc"}` when I am applying sink connector with Json converter for fileStream sink connector i am getting messages as
`{name=abc}`
which is not correct Json. I tried simple string connector but no difference.
Can someone please help me with this.
I want message as it is in file

Answer (score 0):

FileStreamSink always writes Connect Struct toString output, and is not meant to be used in production use cases.

It does not support a `format.class=JSONFormat` such as S3 or HDFS sinks.

As a workaround, you could run Minio as an S3 replacement, or you could use a different sink connector altogether, depending on what you actually want to do with that data. For example, Mongo or JDBC sinks, which respectively offer their own export tooling and can search/analyze your data faster than flat files.